# Why am I getting this code when I console logged the mapped Array in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have been trying to figure this out for nearly 4 hours, any help would be appreciated, I logged the array of objects just before and it worked flawlessly, objects are all working with no issues, and now it's having a meltdown and so will I very soon.

```
    0: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
    1: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
    2: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
    length: 3
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Source code

```
     import React from "react";
     import placeholder from "./placeholder.png";

     function Card(props) {
       const updatedData = props.data;
       console.log(typeof updatedData);
       const newEntry = updatedData.map(function (item) {
         return (
           <div>
             <div className="main-container">
               <div className="main-image">
                 <img src={item.imageUrl} alt="" />
               </div>
               <div className="main-info">
                 <div className="location-container">
                   <img className="placeholder-logo" src={placeholder} alt="" />
                   <p className="location">{item.location}</p>
                   <a href={item.googleMapsUrl}>View on Google Maps</a>
                 </div>
                 <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                 <h4 className="dates">
                   {item.startDate}-{item.endDate}
                      </h4>
                     <p className="description">{item.description}</p>
                   </div>
                </div>
               </div>
             );
            });
          console.log(newEntry);
        }

   export default Card;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the map you are logging? This looks like it's working as expected.

Comment: Can you show us where you're writing your `console.log()`? It looks like you're trying to log the actual React elements.

Comment: @stephancasas 
 I will add in the edit

Comment: @fynmnx I added the full component

Comment: That looks right to me then. You are logging out 3 react elements which exist in the map. What were you expecting?

Comment: What is the actual problem? What's *supposed* to be in `data`? Where is the `data` prop *coming* from?

Comment: You're assigning `newEntry` to the result of `Array.prototype.map()`, and returning an array of React elements from the function you're passing to that. Once logged, `newEntry` is an array of React Elements — not an array of objects.

Comment: right I have an array of object that console.log fine before that, but the second I map them, it gives me the array of React Elements, how do I get it to actually log out the mapped objects.

Comment: @DaveNewton data prop is coming from another component that is passed down to this component.

Comment: @fynmnx im trying to display the objects inside the array now the React elements

Comment: You can just console log `item` inside the map and it'll log every iteration.

Comment: @fynmnx I need to return the content that you see In the source code to display the full card, but it doesn't let me, forgive me but I am fairly new to React and may not understand all of it

Comment: For you to see the content have you declared `<Card {...props}/>` somewhere already?

Comment: If you've run `console.log(updatedData)`, the result you'll see in the console will be what's in the array. Calling `.map()` on an array will create a new array which is made-up of whatever you return from the function you pass into it as the first argument. In this case, you've passed a function which is returning a React element for each item in the array.

Comment: @fynmnx no I have not, I just have a <Card data={data} />

Comment: @stephancasas so how would I retrieve the the full <div>With all my content</div>

Comment: I am a little confused on what you guys are telling me, like I have used the map function before in the exact same way, and it didn't do that in other things I have built, im not being ignorant im just very confused on how to actually fix this.

Comment: What do you see on your screen, does this component even render?

Comment: @fynmnx nope it does not, the thing I posted in the beginning is the exact thing that comes on the console.log, nothing else comes up anywhere

Comment: Found the issue, you're not returning your newEntry.

Comment: @fynmnx im gonna cry.... all this time and it was just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a return on the component.

```
import React from "react";
import placeholder from "./placeholder.png";

function Card(props) {
  const updatedData = props.data;
  console.log(typeof updatedData);
  return updatedData.map(function (item) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main-container">
          <div className="main-image">
            <img src={item.imageUrl} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className="main-info">
            <div className="location-container">
              <img className="placeholder-logo" src={placeholder} alt="" />
              <p className="location">{item.location}</p>
              <a href={item.googleMapsUrl}>View on Google Maps</a>
            </div>
            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            <h4 className="dates">
              {item.startDate}-{item.endDate}
            </h4>
            <p className="description">{item.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```